# EntitySpriteMonster instanceof Entity... that simple and it doesnt work?

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, instanceof

I have code like:

```
class Entity;

class EntityTool extends Entity;
class EntitySprite extends Entity;

class EntityToolSpoon extends EntityTool;
class EntityToolBow extends EntityTool;
class EntitySpritePlayer extends EntitySprite;
class EntitySpriteMonster extends EntitySprite;
```

Now I have a method called `move()` in `Entity`, and some others overwrite it.

Now, if the argument is an `EntitySpriteMonster`, why does this not work:

```
public void foonction(Object wut)
{
    if (wut instanceof Entity) ((Entity)wut).move(x,y);
}
```

The move function (though this is redundant and unneeded. it fails at `if rawpeek instanceof...`):

```
@Override
public void move(double x, double y) {
    super.move(x, y);
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        Object rawpeek = palette.get(i);
        System.out.println(rawpeek);
        if (rawpeek == null) continue;
        if (rawpeek instanceof Entity)
            ((Entity) rawpeek).move(x, y);
    }
}
```

*EDIT: It just aborts. (operator instanceof returns false)*

Eclipse shows me in debug, that `wut` is definetly an `EntitySpriteMonster`.

Comment: Define "not work": What **does** happen when you compile/execute that code?

Comment: What doesn't work? What happens exactly?

Comment: Also: your naming convention is kind-of unusual: why do you include the whole hierarchy in the name? Why isn't it just `Tool`, `Sprite`, `Spoon`, `Bow`, `Player` and `Monster`?

Comment: @Sauer Alphabetical sortage FTW... (it keeps clearness, too)

Comment: Clearness? By adding tons of redundant information to your name? Well, it boils down to style and thus to personal preference. But I, for one, am not a huge fan of [the hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) and similar styles. I'd simply put all of those in an `entity` package and be done with that (maybe even sub-package, depending on the number of classes).

Comment: Why do you put here entities like `EntityToolSpoon` and other that are **irrelevant** for your problem? You could try to simplify to the minimum, and if it is small enough, paste all here.

Comment: Well, i thought that might be because wut is not an instance of Entity directly, as there's EntitySprite between it.... ? --- @edutesoy I have 5800 lines of code, and that stuff is quite a lot of it. I cant shorten it and put here, sorry. In case anyone is still interested, my code is GPLv3 and in here: https://github.com/linuxrocksrulers/worldfix5/tree/

Comment: You can put the class that is in between, but not **unrelated** entities...

Comment: @edu and that means exactly...?

Comment: Would you have another Entity class in another package that you would have imported instead of your actual Entity class, and that would also have a move(x, y) method?

Comment: To debug add `System.out.println(wut.getClass() + " / " + wut.getClass().getClassLoader() + " <-> " + Entity.class + " / " + Entity.class.getClassLoader());` **before** the `instanceof` check and look at the output (post it if it doesn't help you).

Comment: gives me `class model.InventorySlot / sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@61e63e3d <-> class model.Entity / sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@61e63e3d`

Comment: I mean, problem solved. Only thing is that I cannot answer my own question. =(

Comment: @imacake: you should be able to answer your own question (you might have to wait a bit however. So it **wasn't** an `EntitySpriteMonster` after all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

The above use of instanceof was correct.
The problem instead was:

`((Inventory)palette).get(index)` returned an `InventorySlot`, and not a `Entity`. InventorySlot contains Entites, so I was missing to peek the first item from the container.

My correct code should be `Object rawpeek = paltte.get(i).peek();`

Thanks everyone for trying. And sorry for this obvious problem.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason that I know of that code like this fails (when `wut` has been verified to be of the correct type) is that the class of `wut` was loaded by a different classloader than `Entity` as in your class.

A class in Java is identified by it's package name, it's simple name **and** the classloader that loaded it. So `mypackage.Entity` *might* be different from `mypackage.Entity` **if** they have been loaded by separate classloaders.

This usually only happens when you use some kind of plug-in mechanism (OSGi, ...). Do you use something like this?

Comment: nope. just `new`s. i also have a single thread. i am not allowed to use any libraries for my game (university)

Comment: "just news"? I don't understand what you're trying to say. Also: threading is almost definitely not the source of your problem.